# WCF - How to deserialize a byte parameter

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I wrote a WCF restful service that accepts string and a byte parameter. The problem is that the web service works fine if the byte is blank, but if there is a value in the byte parameter then i get the following error message :

'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Byte[]. End element 'Document' from namespace '' expected.

Here is my code

**WCF Interface**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "IDocument")]
string IndexDocument(byte[] Document, string DocumentType);
```

**WCF Interface implementation**

```
public string IndexDocument(byte[] Document, string DocumentType)
{
}
```

**Client program**

```
 private class Documentt
        {
            public byte[] Document { get; set; }
            public string DocumentType { get; set; }
        }



static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog.FileName);

            var parameters = new Documentt()
            {
                Document = bytes,
                DocumentType = "AA"
            };


            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            { 
                var request = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var response = client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:59005/ServiceCall.svc/IDocument"), request);
                var result = response.Result;

            }
        }
```

What am i doing wrong here ? I wanted to make use of bytes because i wanted to write a cross platform(to be used by java, c++, c# etc) web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you are using `datacontact` as your deserilizer and `Json.NET` as your sterilizer.  remember they act differently with some kind of object like `DateTime` and `Byte[]`.
please use this method in order to serialize your request:

```
public static string DataJsonSerializer<T>(T obj)
{
    var json = string.Empty;
    var JsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (var mStrm = new MemoryStream())
    {
        JsonSerializer.WriteObject(mStrm, obj);
        mStrm.Position = 0;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(mStrm))
            json = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return json;
}
```

your request should be like this:

```
var request = new StringContent(DataJsonSerializer(parameters), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Comment: This worked perfectly fine. I had to append DataContract and DataMember to my Document class to allow this solution to work. Thank you..